# In Typescript "keyof Record<string, string>" is not "string"

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm hitting this wall since days now and I'm not sure anymore if I'm the problem or if typescript is broken...

I defined a generic class with the generic extending `Record<string, string>`:

```js
class DbTable<ColumnDefinitions extends Record<string, string>> { /* ... */ }
```

At a later point I want to use the exact keys (e.g. `'id' | 'name'` instead of just `string`), so I use the `keyof` operator on the generic, like this:

```js
function selectFields(fields: (keyof ColumnDefinitions)[]) { /* ... * / }
```

But `keyof ColumnDefinitions` resolves to `string | number | symbol` instead of just being of type `string`.

What did I miss?!

Here is a [TS playground link with an example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgIiAKqZApgDw4IEAeEBAdgCYYBKBsA9lLUZFAJbUDmAGgRdefAHxiEAbwCwAKAQIADlBZV4BWkhbUuAV3hsAFPMWKlekMm6wEUAsFo7kATwTVgAWwIAuYdFEBUzMLKxs7BydqV21kPU9dPyZWdiIAawIXFgAzBBwhEX4xYIBKaQBfeUq5eRQ0DGwAMW4CZA5m1toAOS8CMkoaen8eIulg1l1oAwhjUOtbD28-Drae7yE58OBrNAB+P0K+Mqlq6trUdAQAVTACKDwrPooqOgbcfGIpBG5aA4D+ISLXzDUQIcqSWQKZSWebaSZQabGEqQszCPRKO5GADkeluUCxQi+Pz8WJwAFEABqkAAKDAAkgBZACCDAAmggANJk9ldADypC6VwAMkKCe5eiTyVSEHyBcLReUSsFTvJ5Nk9NR4NwdAgQHpuG0AIp6O4uEj9F5DZJsDiHAr-cRiIwQD5+bAPQgkMRCbItNpgPxGDJZXI4EoAbQAusdgvYIHooNQxlDFC7HkEaimEAB6ABUwVRpGeg0YzBtnAdQgAdDXipnUYoAOoAC2AiDp-Qx8D8wZyeQQAF4hyD+AWzExttwIC4-A2EL3Q4Ph4cEAAfdzxEB3NfCFyeEAsZBj3PZse+zoBhDn-1VzzAJRGa-dXqDyTUAgAdywIBWtEffufbwSiVKEVTkIA).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can [extract](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) only strings from `string | number | symbol` in the method signature.

Instead of

```
fields: (keyof T)[]
```

you can write

```
fields: (Extract<keyof T, string>)[]
```

and the error goes away.

[**TypeScript Playground**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgIiAKqZApgDw4IEAeEBAdgCYYBKBsA9lLUZFAJbUDmAGgRdefAHxiEAbwCwAKAQIADlBZV4BWkhbUuAV3hsAFPMWKlekMm6wEUAsFo7kATwTVgAWwIAuYdFEBUzMLKxs7BydqV21kPU9dPyZWdiIAawIXFgAzBBwhEX4xYIBKaQBfeUq5eRQ0DGwAMW4CZA5m1toAOS8CMkoaen8eIulg1l1oAwhjUOtbD28-Drae7yE58OBrNAB+P0K+Mqlq6trUdAQAVTACKDwrPooqOgbcfGIpBG5aA4D+ISLXzDUQIcqSWQKZSWebaSZQabGEqQszCPRKO5GADkeluUCxQi+Pz8WJwAFEABqkAAKDAAkgBZACCDAAmggANJk9ldADypC6VwAMkKCe5eiTyVSEHyBcLReUSsFTvJ5Nk9NR4NwdAgQHpuG0AIp6O4uEj9F5DZJsDiHAr-cRiIwQD5+bAPQgkMRCbItNpgPxGMmUGDwdKZHJ5e0jcQlADaAF1jsF7BA9FBqGMoYoXY8gjVswgAPQAKmCqNIz0GjGYNs4DqEADpm8UC6jFAB1AAWwEQdP6GPgfgyWVypAAvJOQfxy2YmNtuBAXH52wgR5GJ1PDggAD7ueIgO674QuTwgFjIWclouz32dAMIO-+xueYBKIxP7q9BDjyTUAgAO5YCAKy0B+fpft4JRKlCKpyEAA)

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, the built-in [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html) `Record<T>` adds on the symbol and number type. If you think about what happens in Javascript, which is what typescript compiles to, this makes sense, because you can index with number, string, or symbols.

Ex:

```
const map = {0: "hello"}
//both are valid
map[0] 
map["0"]
```

A simple type check to ensure fieldNames is equal to string should resolve your problem at the end of your sandbox.

```
 fields: fields.map(fieldName => {
  if(typeof fieldName === "string") return new DbField(fieldName)
  else return {}
}
```

Or you can do the following to ensure conversion into string:

```
    fields: fields.map(fieldName => new DbField(fieldName.toString())
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a valuable straight-forward solution. I prefer the other solution because it better separates the static TS type checking and the JS runtime code.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to 'keep hold' of the definition of `Column` through a generic definition of `Row`. This creates type from which Column can be inferred and is as narrow as the generic passed to Row. The below example has no compile errors (not tested for behaviour, though).

Contrast the [original playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgIiAKqZApgDw4IEAeEBAdgCYYBKBsA9lLUZFAJbUDmAGgRdefAHxiEAbwCwAKAQIADlBZV4BWkhbUuAV3hsAFPMWKlekMm6wEUAsFo7kATwTVgAWwIAuYdFEBUzMLKxs7BydqV21kPU9dPyZWdiIAawIXFgAzBBwhEX4xYIBKaQBfeUq5eRQ0DGwAMW4CZA5m1toAOS8CMkoaen8eIulg1l1oAwhjUOtbD28-Drae7yE58OBrNAB%20P0K%20Mqlq6trUdAQAVTACKDwrPooqOgbcfGIpBG5aA4D%20ISLXzDUQIcqSWQKZSWebaSZQabGEqQszCPRKO5GADkeluUCxQi%20Pz8WJwAFEABqkAAKDAAkgBZACCDAAmggANJk9ldADypC6VwAMkKCe5eiTyVSEHyBcLReUSsFTvJ5Nk9NR4NwdAgQHpuG0AIp6O4uEj9F5DZJsDiHAr-cRiIwQD5%20bAPQgkMRCbItNpgPxGDJZXI4EoAbQAusdgvYIHooNQxlDFC7HkEaimEAB6ABUwVRpGeg0YzBtnAdQgAdDXipnUYoAOoAC2AiDp-Qx8D8wZyeQQAF4hyD%20AWzExttwIC4-A2EL3Q4Ph4cEAAfdzxEB3NfCFyeEAsZBj3PZse%20zoBhDn-1VzzAJRGa-dXqDyTUAgAdywIBWtEffufbwSiVKEVTkIA) and the [playground with generic inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBASg9gdwDwGE4BsoQB7AgOwBMBnKY4AJwEt8BzAPigF5YIBjOCw1DAGjMo0GAWABQoSFDToArgFt8SGFlwESsREnLU69Ri2U48RUvGQ0AZhApSMjAPy3MALij4IAN2tQA3GLEA9AFQFpxQhBAARjK0tEJiEtAAkvhWFBQQhMxO8opmWoK69IHBUAB69v6iAIaR2tVswFBs6NXEpAAikQAqtegQSirG6vnaQnpQAN5iUFBgFHB4jZnNcPjaMo2cABQzs3MykehUbFAZ1YRr6CBQwH0QAHLVchCuY3S8e7Ngh8en55d8NdVrIFE8XsRXDB2JxuNJckp6Px3iJRLMAJRTAC%20YhxojELTanUiADEqBB0NwyRTCODoEY1KQUYxpmjVutKJtgDsfkcTm5nq8oNTKXT%20Ly-lBqsc2vY3oVaJjJni8QTWu0oABVYjWXpHemqExQLp6-pISZQKiEeU6Wj8fCCm1CKBYll7CX8jgcihcnbo1n7MgySAUbYAchkOooYf4FqtrjD3QAogANbpQAAKMCSAFkAIIwACaUAA0kniw8APLph6agAydZjApeCeTaagVZr9cbWPRexVVQsMnwjSoayg0SolIAijJrCBBgyjflqvgQHptnd9a4TfdEfwLOTKZCcgpEQBtAC6Sr2GWAMgo%20CmX1u90%20%20LZswCACoX7N00uIwwlwBS2vwAB0kHFB%20gazAA6gAFtUTRJCokCNK4ADWEAgHAFhQOmTBEQItp-qw0pUKAriwVA2G4fhhHESiUAAD5uPIkTeGxxAgHIkQYC%2034BC%20h40ieonHuBcjVGA2wSbSgrMIw7gIMapJHoQckaXS6J9myA6iEAA).

```
type Row<Col extends string> = Record<Col, string>
type Column<R extends Row<string>> = R extends Row<infer Col> ? Col : never ;

// for debugging
type Inferred = Column<Row<string>>
//  ^? type Inferred = string

abstract class DbTable<R extends Row<string>> {
  protected constructor(
    public readonly tableName: string,
    public readonly columnNames: Record<Column<R>, string>
  ) {}
}

class DbField<FieldName extends string> {
  constructor(public name: FieldName, public alias?: string) {}
}

class UserTable extends DbTable<{ id: string, name: string }> {
  public constructor(){
    super('user', { id: 'TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL', name: 'TEXT NOT NULL'})
  }
}

function buildQuery<R extends Row<any>>(table: DbTable<R>, fields: Column<R>[]) {
  return {
    table,
    fields: fields.map(fieldName => new DbField(fieldName))
  }
}
```